# How to move mouse cursor with joystick?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input, mouse, joystick

It seems like this question has already been discussed many times. But I couldn't find the solution for my case. All the discussions are either about camera rotation according to mouse movement or object control via mouse. But I need to control the mouse pointer with joystick (or keyboard). It looks like a really simple question, but I'm confused. Currently, I'm trying to hide hardware cursor and recreat my own, controlling it with `Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")` or `Input.GetAxis("Mouse X")` but the cursor just disappears and Event System reports no movement. However, if I use `Input.mousePosition.x` my custom cursor is well created and controlled with mouse. Unfortunately, I need to control it only with Joystick. In addition, it doesn't work with Project Settings>>Input (or maybe I'm change something wrong there) Thanks in advance.

```
public class cursor : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Texture2D cursorImage;

    private int cursorWidth = 32;
    private int cursorHeight = 32;
    public float horizontalSpeed = 2.0F;
    public float verticalSpeed = 2.0F;

    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        float h = horizontalSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime;
        float v = verticalSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime;
        GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(h, Screen.height - v, cursorWidth, cursorHeight), cursorImage);
    }
}
```

Comment: What about having a canvas overlay with an image on it ? You can use the RectTransform to make it move

Comment: @Jichael Thanks for your suggestion. That's indeed a solution, and I was thinking about that. But the entire app functionality is about mouse position (display coordinates), and I really would prefer not to rewrite everything and obtain this canvas world position and translate it to display coordinates. The project is ready, I only need to implement joystick movement.

Comment: you know that `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0);` does absolutely nothing here, right? it returns a bool you never store or use... If you really want to implement your own cursor with possibility of using UI and `IPointerEnterHandler`, `IPointerClickHandler` etc you would have to implement your own [`PointerInputModule`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.PointerInputModule.html)

Comment: @derHugo I know, these lines are useless here, just leftovers. Sorry, I'll remove them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using

```c#
float h = horizontalSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime;
float v = verticalSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime;
GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(h, Screen.height - v, cursorWidth, cursorHeight), cursorImage);
```

`h` and `v` will always have very tiny values since multiplied by `Time.deltaTime` and `Input.GetAxis` afaik returns usually values between `0` and `1`.

These values don't represent an actual cursor position but rather are the change of the position relative to the last frame.

Your cursor will be stuck somewhere in the top-left corner.

---

Instead you should store the current position and **add** your values as change to it like

```c#
private Vector2 cursorPosition;

private void Start()
{
    Cursor.visible = false;

    // optional place it in the center on start
    cursorPosition = new Vector2(Screen.width/2f, Screen.height/2f);
}

private void OnGUI()
{
    // these are not actual positions but the change between last frame and now
    float h = horizontalSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime;
    float v = verticalSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime;

    // add the changes to the actual cursor position
    cursorPosition.x += h;
    cursorPosition.y += v;

    GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(cursorPosition.x, Screen.height - cursorPosition.y, cursorWidth, cursorHeight), cursorImage);
}
```

---

Also note that `horizontalSpeed` and `verticalSpeed` are in **`Pixels / Seconds`** and you probably want some values bigger then `2` ;)

I used `200` and the <kbd>Up</kbd>, <kbd>Down</kbd>, <kbd>Left</kbd> & <kbd>Right</kbd> keys.

[image]

Comment: That's fantastic, @derHugo ! As always very informative and helpful. Thank you very much!

Comment: I apologize for bothering you again, but I have another problem. Everything works perfect and I get what I need, but there is an issue and maybe you could help me again. I have a multi-display setup and the cursor doesn't go to the second display. Do you know what can cause this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Hm honestly I have zero experience with mutlidisplays in Unity .. my only guess would be that maybe the `OnGUI` does not support multiple displays .. you could try to instead use a normal [`Image`](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui/ui-image) component from the Unity [UI system](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UISystem.html) instead. There also once was an issue with [UI and multiple displays](https://forum.unity.com/threads/ui-and-multiple-displays.385525/) so the UI was enterily limited to the main display .. maybe that's still true for `OnGUI`...

Comment: Thanks. Will try to find something out. Anyway, I always have a solution to simply build a borderless window and drag it to all the displays. Thanks again.